# how to send id in route and controller in laravel localization

Tags: laravel, localization

In my Laravel project with localization I made middleware, route group and all parameters, language switch work correct but when I click to send id by

```php
<a href="{{ route('products', [app()->getLocale(), $category->id]) }}" class=""></a>
```

I get the error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: products] [URI:
>   {lang}/products/{id}]

**My Routes:**

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AppController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/categories', 'AppController@categories')->name('categories');
    Route::get('products/{id}', 'AppController@products')->name('products');

    Auth::routes();
});
```

**My Middleware:**

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    \App::setLocale($request->lang);

    return $next($request);
}
```

**My AppController:**

```php
public function products($id)
{
    $products = Category::with('products')->where('id', $id)->get();

    return view('products', compact('products'));
}
```

this is the URL:

```php
http://127.0.0.1:8000/fa/products/1
```

if I change the above URL manually it works and shows the page:

```php
http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/products/1
```

But if I click on:

```php
<a href="{{ route('products', [app()->getLocale(), $category->id]) }}" class=""></a>
```

I receive the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you added a route prefix the first parameter of the `products` method in your controller will be `lang` and the second one `id`.

This should fix the controller:

```php
public function products($lang, $id)
{
    $products = Category::with('products')->where('id', $id)->get();

    return view('products', compact('products', 'lang'));
}
```

Comment: @Remul.thank you the solution worked: I have language switch:
  `code`@if(app()->isLocale('fa') )
    <div id="change"><a href="{{ route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}">English</a></div>
 @elseif(app()->isLocale('en'))
    <div id="change"><a href="{{ route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), 'fa') }}">فارسی</a></div>
  @endif `code` but it send this error:
Missing required parameters for [Route: products] [URI: {lang}/products/{id}] if I omit language switch and switch manually it works perfect ! help the solution for language switch

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a key-value array in `route('products', ['lang'=>app()->getLocale(), 'id'=>$category->id])` or whatever your route parameters are named in the original route.

Ref. [Laravel Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)

PS. as [Remul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57786018/3591273) notes, since you have a `lang` param (as route prefix) the first param in your controller will be `$lang` then `$id`

```
public function products($lang, $id)
{
    $products = Category::with('products')->where('id', $id)->get();

    return view('products', compact('products'));
}
```